# Bootstrap panels won't align horizontally in tablet view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a small project (http://laurensvandijk.com/as/diensten.html) and I'm trying to get the pricing panels to align horizontally in tablet portrait view. Currently they are stacked on top of each other). I'd like to see them next to each other in tablet view. In mobile view however, I would like them to be stacked on top of each other as it is.

I'm probably missing something in the media queries of my css file, but can't seem to figure out what's making them stack on top of each other when there is clearly enough space available to align them horizontally.

Comment: Which part is the "pricing panel"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry, the pricing panels are the panels which have 'Totaalpakket' in the heading with a greenish background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you have applied to those blocks is `col-lg-4 col-md-4 sm-6`. Note that the last one is missing the `col-` prefix.